# Implementing A Random Image Into A Constant

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

In my to do list app, I would like to select a random image as a background for every task added. I have made the random image picker but I don't know how to put this into the app

This is my random image picker:

```
let backImages = [
    "a.png",
    "b.png",
    "c.png",
    "d.png",
    "e.png",
    ]
///////////

func randomImage() -> UIImage {
    let unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(backImages.count)
    let unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
    let randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)
    return UIImage(named: backImages[randomNumber])!
}
```

And I would like to put randomImage() into where UIImage(named: "a") is currently but I am unsure of how to implement this.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "a")
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just generate a random number and pick from your array:

```
let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt(backImages.count)))
let image = backImages[random]
```

Comment: I have tried this but get this error: "Cannot use instance member "backimages" within property initializer; property initializers run before self is avaliable.    Any ideas? @Code Different

Comment: @LukeRoberts you should try `UIImage(named: backImages[random])`, because you have an array of strings, not of images

Comment: I have put that in but I get yet another error: 'cannot subscript a value of type [string] with an index of type () -> int'. @Code Different